# Does Scrapy support JavaScript for webcrawling?

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I heard that scrapy doesn't support javascript. I wanted to know if i could use scrapy to crawl the links using crawlspider to our intranet site, our intranet site has javascript and i believe it gets generated when you click on a link but I'm not 100% sure.

But the view source is made of xml-stylesheet and it has the same data as the html when i use firebug. I also can't scrape the site using html tags i need to use the xml tags in order to scrape. I am confuse why it has both html and xml and theres data on both and why I can't scrape html only the xml?

I know I can crawl the first page using the xml tags but can I continue to follow a link and keep crawling?

Will i still be able to use scrapy's crawlspider to crawl every link or i can't? If i can't can you suggest another tool i can use? that supports javascripts and post authentication login (https).?

thanks!

Here is the HTML data when i use firebug (same data as the XML)

```
<tr>
<td class="crt">1</td>
<td class="listCell" align="center">
<td class="listCell" align="center">
<a href="/dis/packages.jsp?view=list&show=perdevice&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&subscrbid=6505550000&mdn=6505550000&maxlength=100">probe0</a>
</td>
<td class="listCell" align="center">
<a href="/dis/packages.jsp?view=list&show=perdevice&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&subscrbid=6505550000&mdn=6505550000&maxlength=100">6505550000</a>
</td>
<td class="listCell" align="center">
<a href="/dis/packages.jsp?view=timeline&show=perdevice&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&subscrbid=6505550000&mdn=6505550000&maxlength=100&date=20130716T141624949">2013-07-16 14:16:24.949</a>
</td>
<td class="cell" align="center">2013-07-16 14:16:24.949</td>
<td class="cell" align="left">1 - SMS_PullRequest_CS</td>
<td class="listCell" align="right">
<a href="/dis/profile_download?profileId=4294967295">4294967295</a>
</td>
<td class="listCell" align="center">
<a href="/dis/sessions.jsp?view=list&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&mdn=6505550000&subscrbid=6505550000&maxlength=100">view sessions</a>
</td>
<td class="listCell" align="center">
<a href="/dis/errors_agg.jsp?view=list&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&mdn=6505550000&subscrbid=6505550000&maxlength=100">view errors</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the data when i use view source XML-Stylesheet (same data as the HTML)

```
<row>
<cell type="href" href="/dis/packages.jsp?view=list&show=perdevice&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&mdn=6505550000&subscrbid=6505550000&maxlength=100">6505550000</cell>
<cell type="href" href="/dis/packages.jsp?view=list&show=perdevice&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&subscrbid=6505550000&mdn=6505550000&maxlength=100">probe0</cell>
<cell type="href" href="/dis/packages.jsp?view=list&show=perdevice&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&subscrbid=6505550000&mdn=6505550000&maxlength=100">6505550000</cell>
<cell type="href" href="/dis/packages.jsp?view=timeline&show=perdevice&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&subscrbid=6505550000&mdn=6505550000&maxlength=100&date=20130716T143636194">2013-07-16 14:36:36.194</cell>
<cell type="plain">2013-07-16 14:36:36.194</cell>
<cell type="plain">1 - SMS_PullRequest_CS</cell>
<cell type="href" href="/dis/profile_download?profileId=4294967295">4294967295</cell>
<cell type="href" href="/dis/sessions.jsp?view=list&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&mdn=6505550000&subscrbid=6505550000&maxlength=100">view sessions</cell>
<cell type="href" href="/dis/errors_agg.jsp?view=list&device_gid=3651746C4173775343535452414567746D75643855673D3D53564A6151624D41716D534C68395A6337634E2F62413D3D&hwdid=probe0&mdn=6505550000&subscrbid=6505550000&maxlength=100">view errors</cell>
</row>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically for JS you use a headless browser that will execute your javascript. [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) with scrapy-splash middleware and [Selenium](https://github.com/voliveirajr/seleniumcrawler/blob/master/seleniumcrawler/spiders/seleniumcrawler_spider.py) are two popular choices there.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, am struggling with js scraping... high five there.

one fast way i know if the scrapy responds to js from a particular website, is to check from scrapy shell. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html  you can view how scrapy understands your request url through view(response).

For instance, view(response) doesn't show product reviews from bestbuy, but it's ok with eBay product reviews.

for related search, http://snipplr.com/all/tags/scrapy/ might be helpful.

it might also be useful if you post your spider here.

good luck! message me if you solve it!